# sql query to compare list items with its total

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Product_Code | Product_Name | Amount | Product_Tag
        A    |  Apple       | 20     | smlt 
        B    |  Bat         | 25     | smlt
        C    |  Card        | 30     | smlt
        ST   |  Total       | 75     | smlt
        E    |  EAN         | 25     | lmlt
        F    |  Fran        | 30     | lmlt
        LT   |  Total2      | 55     | lmlt
```

Considering above table as example, i would like to select the line having total value (ST|Total|75|smlt) as 'Total' in one column and,
select the sum of product having product tag 'smlt' in another column (excl. the total line already in the table)

I can now think of two seperate queries, can there be a way to combine the two 
or
have a query that give results only if there is a total mismatch

My two seperate queries:

```
select amount from table1
where Product_Code = 'st'

select Product_Tag, sum (convert(bigint,amount)) as Calculated_Total
from table1 
where not Product_Code = 'st'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum(case when product_tag = 'st' then amount end) as st_amount,
       sum(case when product_name = 'total' then amount end) as total_amount
from table1
where product_tag = 'st' or product_name = 'total';
```

Comment: Yes, Thank You SO much :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```sql
SELECT product_tag, calculated_total, amount_total
FROM (
  SELECT t1.product_tag, SUM(t1.Amount) AS Calculated_total, MAX(t2.Amount) amount_total
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table1 t2 ON (
    (t1.product_tag = 'smlt' AND t2.product_code = 'ST') OR
    (t1.product_tag = 'lmlt' AND t2.product_code = 'LT')
  )  
  WHERE t1.product_code IN ('ST','LT')
  GROUP BY t1.product_tag
) src
--  WHERE Calculated_Total <> Amount_Total
```

Just uncomment the `WHERE` if you want to only return mismatches.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0afde/9)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this did not work, But fortunately, I am learning sub-queries and I will be using your solution logic for my examples :) thanks again

Comment: No problem.  What was the issue with the query?